# How to use implicit intent from non activity class and in fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
ShareLink statLoc;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

statLoc = new ShareLink();
statLoc.execute();
}
```

The above code is my fragment and am executing a class named ShareLink().
In that ShareLink class I used implicit intent to send data like below

```
public class ShareLink extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

String urlShare = DeviceIdGen.hmUrl;

String statusLoc = null;
public static String locLink = null;
private static String loc = null;   
Context context;    
String locUrl;

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {     

    WebServiceTasks wstShare = new WebServiceTasks();
    return wstShare.getMethod(urlShare);
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {   
    super.onPostExecute(result);    

    try {
        JSONObject jResult = new JSONObject(result);
        statusLoc = jResult.getString("status");

        if (statusLoc.equals("success")) {
            loc = jResult.getString("link");                
        locUrl = "My Current Location :" + locLink + "\n\n"
                    + "My Key : " + loc;            

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity((emailIntent).putExtra(
        android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, locUrl));
        } 
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }}}
```

But am not able to achieve it. Please help as am a newbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Edit your AsyncTask,
Add a constructor to it

```
public class ShareLink extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

String urlShare = DeviceIdGen.hmUrl;

String statusLoc = null;
public static String locLink = null;
private static String loc = null;   

String locUrl;

private Context context = null;
    public ShareLink(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {     

    WebServiceTasks wstShare = new WebServiceTasks();
    return wstShare.getMethod(urlShare);
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {   
    super.onPostExecute(result);    

    try {
        JSONObject jResult = new JSONObject(result);
        statusLoc = jResult.getString("status");

        if (statusLoc.equals("success")) {
            loc = jResult.getString("link");                
        locUrl = "My Current Location :" + locLink + "\n\n"
                    + "My Key : " + loc;            

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        context.startActivity((emailIntent).putExtra(
        android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, locUrl));
        } 
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }}}
```

And invoke your AsyncTask as

```
statLoc = new ShareLink(getActivity());
statLoc.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

you could pass a context or an activity to your `ShareLink` class  and use that instance to start your intent. 
for example

```
private Context context;
public ShareLink (Context context){
    this.context = context;
}
```

and then in your `onPostExecute` you can use `context.startActivity()` or whatever you wanna do with the intent.